# How to "extend" a (partial) record selector?

Tags: haskell

**NB:** The type I define below is just a convenient example for the purposes of this question; I'm sure there's no any need for me to roll my own definition of complex numbers in Haskell.

---

I don't know if I'm using the right terminology here, but the selector `r` below is ane example of what I mean by a "partial" record selector:

```
data Complex = Polar       { r :: Float, y :: Float }
             | Rectangular { x :: Float, y :: Float }
             deriving Show
```

`r` is "partial" because it cannot be applied to *all* `Complex` values; e.g.

```
r $ Polar 3 0
-- 3.0
```

...but

```
r $ Rectangular 3 0
-- *** Exception: No match in record selector r
```

In this case, however, there's a sensible definition for `r $ Rectangular x y`, namely:

```
-- assuming {-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
r :: Complex -> Float
r Rectangular { .. } = sqrt $ (x * x) + (y * y)
```

GHCi rejects this definition of `r`, with a `multiple declarations of ‘r’` error.

Is there a way to extend `r` so that it can be applied to *any* `Complex` value?

---

Of course, I realize that I can define something like

```
-- assuming {-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
modulus :: Complex -> Float
modulus Polar       { .. } = r
modulus Rectangular { .. } = sqrt $ (x * x) + (y * y)
```

...but I want to know if it is possible to extend the already existing selector `r`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, and IMO such record selectors should never be introduced in the first place. I'd write this as

```
type ℝ = Float  -- Note that Double is usually more sensible

newtype S¹ = S¹ {ϑ :: ℝ}  -- in [-π, π[
newtype ℝPlus = ℝPlus {posℝ :: ℝ} -- in [0, ∞[

data Complex = Polar ℝPlus S¹
             | Rectangular ℝ ℝ
         deriving Show
```

This way, there is no error potential in form of partial record selectors, and also no confusion what to unpack etc.. Even for such a “non-record type”, you can write your own accessors, preferrably in lens form:

```
import Control.Lens

r :: Lens' Complex ℝPlus
r = lens get set
 where get (Polar r _) = r
       get (Rectangular x y) = ℝPlus . sqrt $ x^2 + y^2
       set (Polar _ θ) r = Polar r θ
       set (Rectangular x y) (ℝPlus r) = Rectangular (x * η) (y * η)
        where η = r / sqrt (x^2 + y^2)
```